# How do I programmatically rename a Sharepoint directory (SPFolder or SPListItem)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2003

I have tried this:

```
SPFolder folder = ...;
folder.Item["Name"] = newName;
folder.Item.Update();
```

And it behaves mysteriously.  If I run it, it throws an exception:

```
 SPException: Cannot complete this action.
```

HOWEVER, if I stop it in the debugger after the new Name assignment and before the Update(), and look at the properties of folder.Item, then continue, it works every time.  It's not a timing thing, I tried stopping it in the debugger without looking at it in the Locals window, but it threw an exception that time.

This question indicates a similar solution but using SystemUpdate(), does that matter?  [Programmatically changing name of SPFolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632389/programmatically-changing-name-of-spfolder)

Answer (score 8):

In a `Document Library` the field `Name` of an item (folder) has `StaticName = FileLeafRef`. So what really worked for me is

```
folder.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.FileLeafRef] = "The new name";
folder.Item.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to change the name, but te title.
So:

```
folder.Item[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title] = newName;
folder.Item.Update(); // or SystemUpdate(false)
```

The difference between Update and SystemUpdate is that Update will change modified / modified by information and if versioning is enabled it will increase the version number. SystemUpdate does not update these.

Also note that I use SPBuiltInFieldId.Title. This is better than using "Title", because "Title" may cause issues in sites that are not in English.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that it was for SharePoint 2003. I don't have any experience in 2003, only 2007 and 2010. It may work like this, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SPFolder attachfolder = documentLibrary.RootFolder.SubFolders[guid];
            //rename guid to new item id
            attachfolder.Properties[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title.tostring()] = itemID;
            attachfolder.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add before the action "**folder.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true**"
and after it bring back the AllowUnsafeUpdates to it's previous value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `MoveTo` method

Answer (score 0):

```
folder.Item["Name"] = newName;
folder.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
folder.Item.Update();
folder.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

this fork for me